# Transform vertical sortable layout to horizontal one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am playing around with drag and drop sortable layout. With the help of google, I've managed to come up with vertical layout that I like. You can see it here:
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d2g2Lspq/). What puzzels me is how to transform this (vertical) layout into horizontal one.

I tried with `float:left`, setting up `.parents` and `buttons` width, but all the attempts were unfruitful.

Converting this to horizontal one seems to be above my expertise. Any idea on how to tackle this?

```js
$(function() {

  $("#clickme").click(function() {
    var elemnew = $("<button id='button1' class='button'>NEWLY ADDED</button>");
    elemnew.insertBefore("#button1");
    elemnew.height(elemnew.width());

  });


  $(".button").height($(".button").width());
  $(".parent").on('mousedown', '.button', function(e) {
    if (e.which === 1) {
      var button = $(this);
      var button_id = button.attr('id');
      var parent_height = button.parent().innerHeight();
      var top = parseInt(button.css('top'));
      var original_ypos = button.position().top; //original ypos
      var drag_min_ypos = 0 - original_ypos;
      var drag_max_ypos = parent_height - original_ypos - button.outerHeight();
      var drag_start_ypos = e.clientY;
      var my_ypos = original_ypos;
      //Set current order for all
      $('.button').each(function(i) {
        $(this).attr('data-order', (i + 1));
      });
      var prev_button = button.prev('.button');
      var next_button = button.next('.button');
      var prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
      var next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
      $('#log1').text('mousedown ' + button_id + ' original_ypos: ' + original_ypos);
      $('#log2').text('');
      $('#log3').text('');
      $(window).on('mousemove', function(e) {
        //Move and constrain
        button.addClass('drag');
        var direction = my_ypos > button.position().top ? 'up' : 'down';
        var new_top = top + (e.clientY - drag_start_ypos);
        my_ypos = button.position().top;
        button.css({
          top: new_top + 'px'
        });
        if (new_top < drag_min_ypos) {
          button.css({
            top: drag_min_ypos + 'px'
          });
        }
        if (new_top > drag_max_ypos) {
          button.css({
            top: drag_max_ypos + 'px'
          });
        }
        $('#log2').text('mousemove new_top: ' + new_top + ', my_ypos: ' + my_ypos + ', direction: ' + direction);
        //$('#log3').text('');
        //Check position over others
        if (direction == 'down' && next_button_ypos != '') {
          if (my_ypos > next_button_ypos) { //crossed next button
            $('#log3').text('dragged after ' + next_button_ypos + ' (' + next_button.attr('id') + ')');
            next_button.css({
              top: (parseInt(next_button.css('top')) - next_button.outerHeight(true)) + 'px'
            }); //up once
            var tmp_order = next_button.attr('data-order');
            next_button.attr('data-order', button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
            button.attr('data-order', tmp_order);
            prev_button = next_button;
            next_button = next_button.nextAll('.button:not(.drag)').first();
            prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
            next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
          }
        } else if (direction == 'up' && prev_button_ypos != '') {
          if (my_ypos < prev_button_ypos) { //crossed prev button
            $('#log3').text('dragged before ' + prev_button_ypos + ', ' + prev_button.attr('id'));
            prev_button.css({
              top: (parseInt(prev_button.css('top')) + prev_button.outerHeight(true)) + 'px'
            }); //down once
            var tmp_order = prev_button.attr('data-order');
            prev_button.attr('data-order', button.attr('data-order')); //switch order
            button.attr('data-order', tmp_order);
            next_button = prev_button;
            prev_button = prev_button.prevAll('.button:not(.drag)').first();
            prev_button_ypos = prev_button.length > 0 ? prev_button.position().top : '';
            next_button_ypos = next_button.length > 0 ? next_button.position().top : '';
          }
        }
        $('#log4').text('prev_button_ypos: ' + prev_button_ypos + ' (' + prev_button.attr('id') + '), next_button_ypos: ' + next_button_ypos + ' (' + next_button.attr('id') + ')');
      });
      $(window).on('mouseup', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 1) {
          $('.button').removeClass('drag');
          $(window).off('mouseup mousemove');
          //Reorder and reposition all
          $('.button').each(function() {
            var this_order = parseInt($(this).attr('data-order'));
            var prev_order = $(this).siblings('.button[data-order="' + (this_order - 1) + '"]');
            if (prev_order.length > 0) {
              $(this).insertAfter(prev_order);
            }
          });
          $('.button').css('top', '0');
          $('.button').removeAttr('data-order'); //reset
          $('#log1').text('mouseup');
          $('#log2').text('');
          $('#log3').text('');
          $('#log4').text('');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: table;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80px;
  clear: both;
  margin: 2px auto;
}

.button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button.drag {
  z-index: 99;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent" class="parent">
  <button id="button1" class="button">Drag me 1</button>
  <button id="button2" class="button">Drag me 2</button>
  <button id="button3" class="button">Drag me 3</button>
  <button id="button3" class="button">Drag me 3</button>
  <button id="button3" class="button">Drag me 3</button>

</div>
<div id="log1"></div>
<div id="log2"></div>
<div id="log3"></div>
<div id="log4"></div>
<button id="clickme">
  CLICK ME FOR MORE
</button>
```

Comment: In terms of CSS the issue is simple, but the main issue is about the JS code which needs to be changed to allow dragging in any direction. CSS: `.parent {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  margin: 20px;
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  clear: none;
  margin: 2px;
  float: left;
}`

Comment: Thanks. I will dive deeper into that. The css you posted represents a partial solution. It's biggest problem is that floated elements get put into the next line, while the preferred solution is to use scrollbar and have all buttons in the same line.